# How to download multiple links into a folder via wget in linux

Tags: linux, wget

When I want to download a file in a folder in Linux via wget I use the following:

```
wget -P /patch/to/folder/ http://example.com/file.zip
```

Now let's say I want to download several files into the same folder and my urls are:

```
http://example.com/file1.zip
http://example.com/file2.zip
http://example.com/file3.zip
```

How can I achieve this in one with command in the same folder /patch/to/folder/?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append more URLs to your command:

```
wget -P /patch/to/folder/ http://example.com/file1.zip http://example.com/file2.zip http://example.com/file3.zip
```

If they only differ by number, you can have bash brace expansion automatically generate all the arguments before `wget` runs:

```
wget -P /patch/to/folder/ http://example.com/file{1..3}.zip
```

You can tell that this is possible from the invocation synopsis in `man wget`, where the `...` is a convention that means it can accept multiple at a time:

```
SYNOPSIS
   wget [option]... [URL]...
```